# How to get clientid from aws app config service

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created application and configuration profile with s3 bucket in AWS app config service .
While trying to fetch configuration data from s3 through app config below parameters required pass but clientid didn't see any where in app config deployment process and its mandatory field.

```
    GetConfigurationRequest request = new GetConfigurationRequest();

    request.setApplication("TEST");
    request.setEnvironment("test-env");
    request.setConfiguration("test-s3");
    request.setClientId(""); // mandatory field
    request.setClientConfigurationVersion("2");

    GetConfigurationResult result = appConfig.getConfiguration(request);
```

Please help to get clientid and how to configure appconfig service in aws.

Answer (score 2):

From AWS Documentations:

> The client-id parameter in the following command is a unique, user-specified ID to identify the client for the configuration.

> A unique application instance identifier called a client ID.

You can give any unique client-id in the request by which you can identify the source of the request.
This id also enables AWS AppConfig to deploy the configuration in intervals, as defined in the deployment strategy.